# Is it possible to make an APK file unaccessable to decompile?

Tags: apk, decompiler

I tried decompiling apkfile with apktool. But it said unaccessable. I think this is not obfuscated. How to make an APK file unaccessable to decompile and make it accessable to decompile?

Bad for bad English.

Here is an APK file.

http://www.mediafire.com/download/k16i71dmwpureta/manastone.ms2.Google.apk

Answer (score 0):

In short no. You can craft a file that breaks specific tools, but there's no way to prevent reverse engineering in general.

That being said, I don't see anything wrong with the apk you posted. I was able to decompile it just fine.